Is writing, "There were spending areas whose expenses grew after a decade." unnatural? Emphasis on "whose"

There were spending areas whose expenses grew after a decade.

I'm unsure if whose is used correctly in the above sentence. Can a spending area have its expense or expenditure?


I'd prefer "spending areas in which expenses grew..." - having areas have or possess expenses seems a bit awkward to me.

I don't like expenses in this context. I'd probably prefer just spending areas that grew..., but if you feel you must include another noun to refer to the specific thing that grew, spending areas where outgoings increased...

Is that okay if I follow an American styleguide and then use a British word like outgoings in the same essay?

Second, can I say "the monthly outgoings on cloths"?
